# CDI Query in JavaEE

Tags: dependency-injection, java-ee-6, cdi, weld

Here's my scenario:

```
public BaseJPARepository implements BaseRepository{}

public AuthorizationsJPARepository extends BaseJPARepository implements AuthorizationsRepository{]

public ClearingJPARepository extends BaseJPARepository implements ClearingRepository{}
```

I want to inject into my Base Facade the `BaseJPARepository`.

CDI throws up the error that `Multiple ambiguous 
dependencies found -> BaseJPARepository,AuthorizationsJPARepository and ClearingJPARepository`. Fair enough, but I need to resolve it as I might just use my `BaseFacade` + `BaseRepository` in many cases.

```
@Inject
BaseRepository baseRepository
```

Answer (score 1):

Your simplest solution is going to be to create and use qualifiers.

Answer (score 0):

Like @LightGuard mentioned using Qualifiers to disambiguate the concrete implementations would resolve the issue or you could use the concrete class as the qualifying injection point. Here is an article about using [Qualifiers in JavaEE](https://readlearncode.com/deep-dive-factory-pattern/) that might help.